# Compile a static file into an executable

Tags: c, compilation

Say I have a program that creates a database file, and imports data to it from a `.sql` file.

If I don't want a random `.sql` file floating around my directory, is there a way to compile this static file into the executable for use without having to copy it's contents into a string in a C file? A define statement perhaps?

Comment: Using sqlite?  How is this database file created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the statements in the SQL file into a set (an array) of strings, put the strings in a source file and build your application with that. Use `#define` to create names for the indexes into the array.

Comment: So there's no way I can just get an sql dump from sqlite and load it from C without having to have the sql file separate?

Answer (score 4):

Use `xxd`

```
$ xxd -i data.sql > data.sql.c
```

then include (**or copy/paste**) the resulting c file (not a header)

You can include for global ...

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "data.sql.c" /* global scope */
```

... or function scope

```
int foo(void) {
#    include "data.sql.c" /* function scope */
}
```

Comment: Are you supposed to include the data file twice? Or are you just showing that you can include it either inside or outside a function?

Comment: Nice, I decided it would cut down on space to just work some `sed` on it to turn it into an array.

Comment: @ugoren: the double `#include` was just an example (but you could duplicate it and shadow the global variable(s))

Answer (score 2):

Find a utility that will convert an arbitrary binary file into an object file (e.g. bin2obj on Linux).  Then you can simply link the data into your exe without having to convert it into C source code.